# Are pre-duals dense if the duals are dense?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

Assume we have two Banach spaces $X,Y$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $X' \subset Y'$ is a dense subset (with respect to the norm of $Y'$). My question is: Is $Y \subset X$ a dense subset (with respect to the norm of $X$)?

Here, $X'$ denotes the dual space of $X$, i.e. all continuous linear functionals $T:X \longrightarrow \mathbb R$.

I am particularly interested in the example where $X' = W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and $Y = L^1(\Omega)$ (so $Y' = L^\infty(\Omega)$).

As far as I know, there is no explicit characterisation of $X$.

Thank you guys very much in advance.

Comment: Would $Y=c$, $X=c_0$ with $X'=Y'=\ell^1$ count as a counterexample to the general claim?

Comment: @daw: Isn't the "limit functional" in the dual space of $Y$, but not in $\ell^1$?

Comment: The dual space of $c$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$, and this is true for $c_0$ as well. So all these spaces $c',c_0', \ell^1$ are isomorphic, hence 'equal'. I think, the question should be made more precise  in what 'densely imbedded' means for the dual spaces.

Comment: @daw: Thank you for the comment. I edited my post accordingly: I wrote "dense subset", which should clarify the question.